# How to move a parent div from a button

Tags: javascript, html, mouse

This probably very easy to do but I'm finding it frustrating, how can I move an entire div by holding mousedown on a button?

```js
    
    var m = document.getElementById('aboutpanel');
    m.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    
    function mouseUp() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
    }
    
    function mouseDown(e) {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
    }
    
    function move(e) {
        m.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        m.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    };
```

```css
#aboutpanel{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutpanel">
  <input id="exit_about" type="button" onclick="ignore_about()" value="X">
  <input id="mini_about" type="button" onclick="shrink_about()" value="_">
  <input id="title_about" type="button" onclick="" value="About">
  <p>Desklogger OS</p>
  <p>Version: v3.0a</p>
  <p>Credits: Lèla Null</p>
</div>
```

I want to be able to move the div only when the About button is pressed.

Comment: --> https://jsfiddle.net/p1h7ejvz/ This is working. What is the issue?

Comment: It is very close to what I need yes, but it also moves no matter where I click on the div. In the end I want to have a couple forms that are movable but only from a click to move button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function about() {
    document.getElementById('aboutpanel').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('settings').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('about_appstatus').src = 'data/green-dot.png';
    start2();
}

function ignore_about() {
    document.getElementById('aboutpanel').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('about_appstatus').src = 'data/red-dot.png';
}

var m = document.getElementById('title_about'); // Changed
m.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
}

function move(e) {
    document.getElementById('aboutpanel').style.top = e.clientY + 'px'; // Changed
    document.getElementById('aboutpanel').style.left = e.clientX + 'px'; // Changed
}
```

```css
#aboutpanel
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <div id="aboutpanel">
  <input id="exit_about" type="button" onclick="ignore_about()" value="X">
  <input id="mini_about" type="button" onclick="shrink_about()" value="_">
  <input id="title_about" type="button" onclick="" value="About">
  <p>Desklogger OS</p>
  <p>Version: v3.0a</p>
  <p>Credits: Lèla Null</p>
</div>
```

Here's a working solution. I commented the lines I changed.

Comment: Hmm, it works here but not in the main project. Strange, but I fear that might be my problem now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: something about this line `m.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);` is not compatible. Any quick ideas?